Show App Open Ads in Admob JAVA does not open the main activity, after the announcement it gets stuck in the splash activity
I implemented the admob opening announcement in my Java application, I tested it on apis 24 to 34 and the application worked 100% with the admob test ads. However, when I enter the admob ad codes to place the application on Google Play, the app does not go beyond the splash activity.
My Code is: SplashActivity.java
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView imageView;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "SplashActivity";
private final AtomicBoolean isMobileAdsInitializeCalled = new AtomicBoolean(false);
private GoogleMobileAdsConsentManager googleMobileAdsConsentManager;
private long secondsRemaining;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.myanim);
    imageView.setAnimation(anim);

    //admob
    MobileAds.initialize(this);
    Application application = getApplication();
    ((MyApplication) application).loadAd(this);

    // Create a timer so the SplashActivity will be displayed for a fixed amount of time.
    createTimer(Config.SPLASH_DURACAO);

    googleMobileAdsConsentManager =
            GoogleMobileAdsConsentManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    googleMobileAdsConsentManager.gatherConsent(
            this,
            consentError -> {
                if (consentError != null) {
                    // Consent not obtained in current session.
                    Log.w(
                            LOG_TAG,
                            String.format(
                                    "%s: %s", consentError.getErrorCode(), consentError.getMessage()));
                }

                if (googleMobileAdsConsentManager.canRequestAds()) {
                    initializeMobileAdsSdk();
                }

                if (secondsRemaining <= 0) {
                    startMainActivity();
                }
            });

    // This sample attempts to load ads using consent obtained in the previous session.
    if (googleMobileAdsConsentManager.canRequestAds()) {
        initializeMobileAdsSdk();
    }
}
/**
 * Create the countdown timer, which counts down to zero and show the app open ad.
 *
 * @param time the number of milliseconds that the timer counts down from
 */
private void createTimer(long time) {
    //final TextView counterTextView = findViewById(R.id.timer);

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer =
            new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    secondsRemaining = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) + 1;
                    //counterTextView.setText("App is done loading in: " + secondsRemaining);
                }

                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    secondsRemaining = 0;
                    //counterTextView.setText("Done.");

                    Application application = getApplication();
                    ((MyApplication) application)
                            .showAdIfAvailable(
                                    SplashActivity.this,
                                    new MyApplication.OnShowAdCompleteListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onShowAdComplete() {
                                            // Check if the consent form is currently on screen before moving to the
                                            // main
                                            // activity.
                                            if (googleMobileAdsConsentManager.canRequestAds()) {
                                                startMainActivity();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                }
            };
    countDownTimer.start();
}

private void initializeMobileAdsSdk() {
    if (isMobileAdsInitializeCalled.getAndSet(true)) {
        return;
    }

    // Initialize the Mobile Ads SDK.
    MobileAds.initialize(this);

    // Load an ad.
    Application application = getApplication();
    ((MyApplication) application).loadAd(this);
}

/** Start the MainActivity. */
public void startMainActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}

}
My Code is: MyApplication.java
public class MyApplication extends Application
    implements ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, DefaultLifecycleObserver {

private AppOpenAdManager appOpenAdManager;
private Activity currentActivity;
private static final String TAG = "MyApplication";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    this.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);

    ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
    appOpenAdManager = new AppOpenAdManager();
}

/**
 * DefaultLifecycleObserver method that shows the app open ad when the app moves to foreground.
 */
@Override
public void onStart(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner) {
    DefaultLifecycleObserver.super.onStart(owner);
    // Show the ad (if available) when the app moves to foreground.
    appOpenAdManager.showAdIfAvailable(currentActivity);
}

/** ActivityLifecycleCallback methods. */
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@NonNull Activity activity, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    // An ad activity is started when an ad is showing, which could be AdActivity class from Google
    // SDK or another activity class implemented by a third party mediation partner. Updating the
    // currentActivity only when an ad is not showing will ensure it is not an ad activity, but the
    // one that shows the ad.
    if (!appOpenAdManager.isShowingAd) {
        currentActivity = activity;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(@NonNull Activity activity) {}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(@NonNull Activity activity) {}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(@NonNull Activity activity) {}

@Override
public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(@NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull Bundle outState) {}

@Override
public void onActivityDestroyed(@NonNull Activity activity) {}

/**
 * Load an app open ad.
 *
 * @param activity the activity that shows the app open ad
 */
public void loadAd(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    // We wrap the loadAd to enforce that other classes only interact with MyApplication
    // class.
    appOpenAdManager.loadAd(activity);
}

/**
 * Shows an app open ad.
 *
 * @param activity the activity that shows the app open ad
 * @param onShowAdCompleteListener the listener to be notified when an app open ad is complete
 */
public void showAdIfAvailable(
        @NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull OnShowAdCompleteListener onShowAdCompleteListener) {
    // We wrap the showAdIfAvailable to enforce that other classes only interact with MyApplication
    // class.
    appOpenAdManager.showAdIfAvailable(activity, onShowAdCompleteListener);
}

/**
 * Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when an app open ad is complete
 * (i.e. dismissed or fails to show).
 */
public interface OnShowAdCompleteListener {
    void onShowAdComplete();
}

/** Inner class that loads and shows app open ads. */
private class AppOpenAdManager {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AppOpenAdManager";
    //private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/9257395921";

    private final GoogleMobileAdsConsentManager googleMobileAdsConsentManager =
            GoogleMobileAdsConsentManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    private AppOpenAd appOpenAd = null;
    private boolean isLoadingAd = false;
    private boolean isShowingAd = false;

    /** Keep track of the time an app open ad is loaded to ensure you don't show an expired ad. */
    private long loadTime = 0;

    /** Constructor. */
    public AppOpenAdManager() {}

    /**
     * Load an ad.
     *
     * @param context the context of the activity that loads the ad
     */
    private void loadAd(Context context) {
        // Do not load ad if there is an unused ad or one is already loading.
        if (isLoadingAd || isAdAvailable()) {
            return;
        }

        isLoadingAd = true;
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        AppOpenAd.load(
                context,
                getString(R.string.banner_admob_open_ads),
                request,
                new AppOpenAdLoadCallback() {
                    /**
                     * Called when an app open ad has loaded.
                     *
                     * @param ad the loaded app open ad.
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(AppOpenAd ad) {
                        appOpenAd = ad;
                        isLoadingAd = false;
                        loadTime = (new Date()).getTime();

                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdLoaded.");
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "onAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    /**
                     * Called when an app open ad has failed to load.
                     *
                     * @param loadAdError the error.
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        isLoadingAd = false;
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad: " + loadAdError.getMessage());
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "onAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }

    /** Check if ad was loaded more than n hours ago. */
    private boolean wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(long numHours) {
        long dateDifference = (new Date()).getTime() - loadTime;
        long numMilliSecondsPerHour = 3600000;
        return (dateDifference < (numMilliSecondsPerHour * numHours));
    }

    /** Check if ad exists and can be shown. */
    private boolean isAdAvailable() {
        // Ad references in the app open beta will time out after four hours, but this time limit
        // may change in future beta versions. For details, see:
        // https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9341964?hl=en
        return appOpenAd != null && wasLoadTimeLessThanNHoursAgo(4);
    }

    /**
     * Show the ad if one isn't already showing.
     *
     * @param activity the activity that shows the app open ad
     */
    private void showAdIfAvailable(@NonNull final Activity activity) {
        showAdIfAvailable(
                activity,
                new OnShowAdCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onShowAdComplete() {
                        // Empty because the user will go back to the activity that shows the ad.
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Show the ad if one isn't already showing.
     *
     * @param activity the activity that shows the app open ad
     * @param onShowAdCompleteListener the listener to be notified when an app open ad is complete
     */
    private void showAdIfAvailable(
            @NonNull final Activity activity,
            @NonNull OnShowAdCompleteListener onShowAdCompleteListener) {
        // If the app open ad is already showing, do not show the ad again.
        if (isShowingAd) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The app open ad is already showing.");
            return;
        }

        // If the app open ad is not available yet, invoke the callback then load the ad.
        if (!isAdAvailable()) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The app open ad is not ready yet.");
            onShowAdCompleteListener.onShowAdComplete();
            if (googleMobileAdsConsentManager.canRequestAds()) {
                loadAd(currentActivity);
            }
            return;
        }

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Will show ad.");

        appOpenAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(
                new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                    /** Called when full screen content is dismissed. */
                    @Override
                    public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                        // Set the reference to null so isAdAvailable() returns false.
                        appOpenAd = null;
                        isShowingAd = false;

                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.");
                        //Toast.makeText(activity, "onAdDismissedFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        onShowAdCompleteListener.onShowAdComplete();
                        if (googleMobileAdsConsentManager.canRequestAds()) {
                            loadAd(activity);
                        }
                    }

                    /** Called when fullscreen content failed to show. */
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                        appOpenAd = null;
                        isShowingAd = false;

                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: " + adError.getMessage());
                        //Toast.makeText(activity, "onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        onShowAdCompleteListener.onShowAdComplete();
                        if (googleMobileAdsConsentManager.canRequestAds()) {
                            loadAd(activity);
                        }
                    }

                    /** Called when fullscreen content is shown. */
                    @Override
                    public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onAdShowedFullScreenContent.");
                        //Toast.makeText(activity, "onAdShowedFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        isShowingAd = true;
        appOpenAd.show(activity);
    }
}

}
My Code is: AndroidManifest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<!-- For apps targeting Android 13 or higher & GMA SDK version 20.3.0 or lower -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:noHistory="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".BombaActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/granada_sons"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FavoritosActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/favoritos_sons"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SonsActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/todos_sons"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="@string/admob_app_id"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.flag.NATIVE_AD_DEBUGGER_ENABLED"
        android:value="false" />
</application>

